# How to set overriding models in swagger-maven-plugin 3.1.0

Tags: maven, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-maven-plugin

How to set overriding models in swagger-maven-plugin 3.1.0 and Swagger UI 2.0 (or newer versions)?

Recently we've upgraded Swagger UI from 1.2 to 2.0 and swagger-maven-plugin from 2.3 to 3.1.0.

It appears, that swagger-maven-plugin version 3.1.0 is missing the 
`overridingModels` option, that was present in version 2.3.

The option enabled us to customize schema description for certain data types, as described in: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/overriding-models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I eventually solved the problem (I'm using swagger-maven-plugin version 3.1.1):

Let's assume you want to map `java.util.Date` as this arbitrary structure:

```
{
  "year": "string",
  "month": "string",
  "day": "string"
}
```

Step 1: Create a class describing the above model:

```
package com.example;

import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;

@ApiModel
public class MyDate {

    @ApiModelProperty
    public String year;

    @ApiModelProperty
    public String month;

    @ApiModelProperty
    public String day;
}
```

Note: The class name and the package name are arbitrary, they just need to be on the classpath, so the class is visible to the plugin like the rest of your model.

Step 2: In the `pom.xml` add this line to the configuration of the swagger-maven-plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <apiSources>
      <apiSource>
        ...
        <modelSubstitute>/model-substitute.csv</modelSubstitute>
      </apiSource>
    </apiSources>
  </configuration>
  ...
</plugin>
```

Step 3: Create a file `model-substitute.csv` with the following mapping:

```
java.util.Date : com.example.MyDate
```

Put the file in the same maven module as the plugin, in directory `src/main/resources`.
Note: The name of the file is arbitrary, but it should match the value in the pom.xml.

Comment: In this case I just got an null pointer: Failed to execute goal com.github.kongchen:swagger-maven-plugin:3.1.3:generate (default) on project xxx: null: MojoExecutionException: NullPointerException

Comment: @spyro Run mvn with -X option to see full stack trace. It might help solving your issue.

Answer (score 0):

NullPointerException can be because you don't have the file inside of src/main/resources. This is working for me in 3.1.7 version